# Use native library on application Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

How can i use a native library on an Wildfly 8/10 Application Server? Let's say we have to use a native library in a WebService on an application server. In the normal Java Application i can set the VM-arguments to java.library.path with: -Djava.library.path=.

When i try to instantiate a simple object (in the example it is Network-POJO) from the API, i always get:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: smile/Network

I tried:
- to add them in the build path
 [image: error]

2:Try in the code...

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "D:/Development/libs/JSmile");
String s = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
System.loadLibrary("jsmile");
```

Same error. What can i do? In a normal Java Application it is working. Do i have to register it in the wildfly? What i need to do too bring it to work on wildfly (10)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export the path to the library as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and then boot up the server. That way it will pick up the library.